# How to update database upon form data

Tags: php, sql

I wrote some code that gets data from the database and shows it on a page. With the "change" button that hrefs to a page you should update the data in the database with the form input, but I don't know how I can let it update.
The edit_serie.php page is a change-able form that should update the entered data in the database, but I don't know how to do it.
The code of **edit_serie.php**:

```
<?php
function select($query) 
{
    $host = 'localhost';
    $db   = 'netland';
    $user = 'root';
    $pass = '';

    $dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;";
    $options = [
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
        PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
        PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
    ];

    try {
        $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $options);
    } catch (\PDOException $e) {
        throw new \PDOException($e->getMessage(), (int)$e->getCode());
    }
    // Er word ervoor gezorgd dat de database info in rijen komt door queries die uitgevoerd worden
    $rawResult = $pdo->query($query);
    while ($row = $rawResult->fetch()) {
        foreach ($row as $column => $value) {
            $rowResult[$column] = $value;
        }
        $endResult[] = $rowResult;
    }
    return $endResult;
}

$id = $_GET['id'];

if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $rows = select('SELECT * FROM series WHERE id = ' . $id);
    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        echo "
        <a href='index.php'>Terug</a>
        <h1>${row['title']} - ${row['rating']}</h1>
        <table>
        <tr>
        <th>Awards</th>
        <form action='' method='POST'>
        <td><input type='text' name='has_won_awards' value='${row['has_won_awards']}'</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <th>Seasons</th>
        <td><input type='text' name='seasons' value='${row['seasons']}'</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <th>Country</th>
        <td><input type='text' name='country' value='${row['country']}'</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <th>Language</th>
        <td><input type='text' name='language' value='${row['language']}'</td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        <textarea rows='10' cols='40' name='description'>'${row['description']}'</textarea>
        <br><br>
        <input type='button' value='Change'></form>
        ";
    }
};
?>
```

Here are some screenshots of the pages:

**serie.php**
[image]
**edit_serie.php**

[image]
[image]

Comment: Your code is wide open to SQL injection. Use a Prepared Statement rather than embedding user supplied input in the sql

Comment: You have several errors in your code. The `FORM` element must either be wholly contained within a single table cell OR the entire table must be wholly contained within the `form`. The input elements, such as `<input type='text' name='has_won_awards' ` are unclosed

Comment: When you reach a _"but I don't know how to do it"_ point with something this basic, then that probably means you should be sticking your nose into a couple of beginner tutorials at this point.

Comment: That's why I am here, I already looked up tutorials but almost all tutorials use mysqli and i need pdo

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius Yes the form element needs to be as you say, but you can have inputs outside of the form tags if you give them a `form="my-form-id"` attribute.

Comment: @mark_b - Indeed you can - I was not disputing that at all but the above markup has errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Breaking the db connection and query from the function you can study the following to get an understanding of how you might accomplish the editing of individual records. The db connection has to be used for both the `select` and the `update` which is why I placed a single connection before other code.

The generated HTML has been corrected and a new, hidden input added that uses the `id` value. You could use the value from `$_GET['id']`in the db update but I elected to use a hidden input. I think the update code is fairly clear and self-explanatory but you really need to become familiar with [stored procedures](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) - or, perhaps a [better reference on PHPDelusions.net](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo)

```
<?php

    $host = 'localhost';
    $db   = 'netland';
    $user = 'root';
    $pass = '';




    $dsn = sprintf("mysql:host=%s;dbname=%s;",$host,$db);
    $options = [
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
        PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
        PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
    ];

    try {
        $pdo = new PDO( $dsn, $user, $pass, $options );
    } catch ( PDOException $e ) {
        exit($e->getMessage());
    }

    
    
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && isset(
        $_POST['id'],
        $_POST['title'],
        $_POST['has_won_awards'],
        $_POST['rating'],
        $_POST['seasons'],
        $_POST['country'],
        $_POST['language'],
        $_POST['description']
    )){
    
        $sql='update `series` set 
                `title`=:title,
                `rating`=:rating,
                `has_won_awards`=:has_won_awards,
                `seasons`=:seasons,
                `country`=:country,
                `language`=:language,
                `description`=:description
            where `id`=:id';
            
            
        $stmt=$pdo->prepare( $sql );
        $stmt->execute(array(
            ':id'               =>  $_POST['id'],
            ':title'            =>  $_POST['title'],
            ':rating'           =>  $_POST['rating'],
            ':has_won_awards'   =>  $_POST['has_won_awards'],
            ':seasons'          =>  $_POST['seasons'],
            ':country'          =>  $_POST['country'],
            ':language'         =>  $_POST['language'],
            ':description'      =>  $_POST['description']
        ));
    }
    
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>Edit</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php
    
        if( isset( $_GET['id'] ) ) {
            $sql='SELECT
                    `id`,
                    `title`,
                    `rating`,
                    `has_won_awards`,
                    `seasons`,
                    `country`,
                    `language`,
                    `description` 
                FROM series 
                WHERE `id`=:id';
                
            $stmt=$pdo->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->execute(array(
                ':id'   =>  $_GET['id']
            ));
            

            while( $rs=$stmt->fetch( PDO::FETCH_OBJ ) ){
                printf('
                    
                    <a href="index.php">Terug</a>
                    <h1>%1$s - %2$s</h1>
                    
                    <form method="POST">
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Title</th>
                                <td><input type="text" name="title" value="%1$s" /></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Awards</th>
                                <td><input type="text" name="has_won_awards" value="%3$s" /></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Seasons</th>
                                <td><input type="text" name="seasons" value="%4$s" /></td>  
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Rating</th>
                                <td><input type="text" name="rating" value="%2$s" /></td>   
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Country</th>
                                <td><input type="text" name="country" value="%6$s" /></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Language</th>
                                <td><input type="text" name="language" value="%7$s" /></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                        
                        <textarea rows="10" cols="40" name="description">%8$s</textarea>
                        
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        
                        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="%9$s" />
                        <input type="submit" value="Change" />
                    </form>',
                    
                    $rs->title,
                    $rs->rating,
                    $rs->has_won_awards,
                    $rs->seasons,
                    $rs->rating,
                    $rs->country,
                    $rs->language,
                    $rs->description,
                    $rs->id
                );
            }
        }else{
            ob_clean();
            exit(http_response_code(404));
        }
    ?>
    </body>
</html>
```